# hyperbolic quadrilateral angles

Tags: geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

On the hyperbolic plane, if I have a quadrilateral that has all congruent interior angles $\alpha$, how do I figure out what $\alpha$ is? I know in Euclidean geometry one could just use $\frac{180(n-2)}{n}$.

Comment: Do you mean quadrilateral, that is specifically four sides, or polygon?  You use of $n$ indicates you may be interested in more general polygons.  I think the answer is the same, as given by Berci.

Answer (score 3):

This can be any $\alpha<\displaystyle\frac{180^\circ(n-2)}n$. (For any such $\alpha$ *there exists* an $n$-gon with equal sides.)

For illustration, pick a regular $n$-gon, and zoom its vertices out from the center of the $n$-gon (equally raise the distance on the rays from the center), then connect again the new $n$ vertices. You will get a regular $n$-gon with bigger area and smaller angles.

Comment: So, their is not a particular answer then? Their are many answers?

Comment: For a quadrilateral with all equal interior angles?

Comment: Well, there is no regular zooming in hyperbolic plane (at least which preserves lines), but the vertices can be zoomed out and they will form a bigger/smaller regular $n$-gon with smaller/bigger angle (remember that the sum of the angles is in correlation with the area).

Comment: Wait, what do you mean Berci?

Comment: He means something like this picture ($n=8$): https://simonsfoundation.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Haken_sized_Figure04-300x300.jpg